# Deploy pure python to heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I "finished" a little python project and I want to deploy it on heroku
[GitHub page](https://github.com/ttouch/panager).
I want to execute: python2 main.py -i json-rpc
in order to have the json-rpc server listening for connections
but I get the following error when pushing to heroku:

> $ git push heroku master  Counting objects: 153, done. Delta
>   compression using up to 8 threads. Compressing objects: 100% (87/87),
>   done. Writing objects: 100% (153/153), 43.42 KiB, done. Total 153
>   (delta 61), reused 153 (delta 61)
>
> -----> Heroku receiving push  !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
>
> To git@heroku.com:panager.git  ! [remote rejected] master -> master
>   (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to
>   'git@heroku.com:panager.git'

Comment: Did you remember to actually create a Heroku app to push to?  (Either on the heroku site, but preferably through the command line.)  If not, go to the main folder of your project, and run the heroku toolbelt command `heroku create`, and then try `git push heroku master`.

Comment: FYI, you're also missing the `requirements.txt` necessary for Heroku to install Python dependencies you might need.  Have you read [Getting Started with Python on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python)?

Comment: yes I did. I destroied and recreated the app several times... no luck...

Comment: i do not have any requirements. all the functions that i use are standard.take a look: https://github.com/ttouch/panager

Comment: Also, it looks like you're missing a `virtualenv`, since I don't see one on Github and there's no `.gitignore` to ignore it.  `virtualenv`s are requirements for Python apps on Heroku.

Comment: for all projects? I saw it on heroku wiki but i didn't understood it.

Comment: created venv. just like the wiki! I activate it and my program works out of the box! but I get the same error when trying to upload to heroku...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you might want to try doing is creating a Procfile.  The full filename is `Procfile`, no extension, and it goes in the main directory of your project folder.

The content of that file would be:

```
web: python main.py -i json-rpc
```

Give that a shot and see if it works.

Alternatively, you may have forgotten to create a `virtualenv` for your app.

You should follow the instructions in Heroku's guide [Getting Started with Python on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python)

#### Update:

Having finally tested this myself on a fresh Heroku app, what you're missing is a `requirements.txt`.  Even though you don't have any dependencies, you still need it.  Within your virtualenv in the main project folder, run `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, and then `git add .` then `git commit -m "added requirements.txt"`, and then push to Heroku and it should work.

Comment: see updated answer.  you needed the virtualenv, and the `Procfile`, and the `requirements.txt`.  You can't just leave out pieces from the tutorial.

Comment: I was able to launch with just `Procfile` and `requirements.txt`. No need for virtualenv. Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure that requirements.txt is saved with ANSI encoding, not Unicode or UTF-8! If you're a total n00b like me you can simply open requirements.txt in Notepad, choose SAVE AS and change the "Encoding" from the drop down. I tried all of the recommendations above but my error was due to this simple encoding problem.